# How to get a src in template that works on different levels of depth

Tags: html, src

A template builds a file that can be stored in:

***project/output/***

or:

***project/output/type/***

I want to access static files stored in:
***project/output/static***
How to make it so it has the right src= in both cases?

```
src="project/output/static"
```

won't work locally because locally you need:
home/user/project/output

This works for both production and locally but only in 1 case of 2:
../../output/static etc.

Root relative url should work(**/output/static**) but instead of:

***home/user/project/output/static***

it points to:

***output/static***

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: Not really as when I use /output/static/ locally it links to only it without project before it. If I use project in it it won't work for production. From these Examples none seem to fit

Comment: Then you'll need to do something in whatever language you've written your template in, but you don't mention what that is, so it's hard for anyone to help with it.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're saying. The template is written in html. What context should I add? File generation is done in python but it is over thousand of lines of code and I was hoping for a solution that doesn't interfere the generator

Comment: A "template" generally has variables, conditions, that kind of thing; HTML on its own doesn't have those things, so "HTML template" would normally refer to the thing that was *generating* the HTML. If you need to have a different base URL on different servers, having that base URL as a variable in that template is probably the best way to do it.